# Windows to Unix FTP script (Batch)

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, ftp, batch-processing

I have a problem with my batch script.
*---------

`line 1   ftp 101.101.101.162    (remote machine)
 line 2   xxxxxxx                (username)
 line 3   xxxxxxx                (password)`
*-------

When I ran this script on cmd ftp connection was succesfull.
But it didn't fill username and password as you seen up.
So it didn't pass the username and password.

Comment: You don't have an FTP script by the look of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare all the commands and create an input file (what foxdrive was talking about), like so:

```
:: Username
echo xxxxxxx > "%temp%\ftp_commands.txt"

:: Password
echo xxxxxxx >> "%temp%\ftp_commands.txt"
ftp 101.101.101.162 -s:"%temp%\ftp_commands.txt"
```

I'm assuming that you're using the windows ftp command